# Next.js Компонент для проверки доступа к странице

Tags: reactjs, nextjs, next.js

**Доброго времени суток!**

Пишу небольшое web приложение на Next.js. Потребовалось разграничить доступ на обычные страницы и страницы админа. Все страницы админа я обертываю `<isAdmin> ... </isAdmin>`

Код компонента:

```js
const isAdmin = ({ children }) => {
    const check = auth_admin()
    console.log(check)
        if (check) {
           render() ( {children} )
        }
        else { return Router.push('/admin/login') }
}

export default isAdmin
```

Мое понимание работы компонентов видимо не верное. Функция auth_admin() возвращает true либо false. Но страница не отрисовывается c ошибкой: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Comment: __не отрисовывается c ошибкой__ ?А в чем тогда проблема ?

Comment: что тут не понятно?

Comment: Если страница не отрисовывается c ошибкой то тогда как он отрисовывается ?

Comment: Страница не отображается... выдавая при этом ошибку ( скрин ошибки я предоставил ). Суть вопроса в том чтобы создать компонент который будет проверять актуальность токена и если он отсутствует перенаправлять на страницу авторизации

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Мое понимание работы компонентов видимо не верное.*

Действительно ваше понимание работы компонентов не верное.Не знаю где вы видели метод `render` внутри функциональных компонентов.

```
const isAdmin = ({ children }) => {
    const check = auth_admin()

    if(check){
       return {children}
    } else {
       Router.push('/admin/login')
    }
}

export default isAdmin
```

Метод `render` надо использовать только внутри классовых компонентах.Также советую вместо вашей логики использовать логику которое описано внизу.

Пример компонента:

```
const secretPage = ({ check }) => {
    if(check){
      return <h2>Secret value</h2>
    } else {
      return <p>You are not authenticated</p>
    }
}
```

Если защищенных страниц будет много можем просто перенести эту логику в компоненты высшего порядка.

```
export default function(Component){
  return class checkAuth extends Component {
     renderProtectedPage = () => {
         const { check } = this.props;

         if(check){
            return <Component {...this.props} />
         } else {
            return <p>You are not authenticated</p>
         }

     }
     render(){
        return this.renderProtectedPage();
     }
  }
}
```

И в конце импортируем наш HOC и пишем так:

```
import checkAuth from "./";

const secretPage = () => {
    return <p>You are not authenticated</p>
}

export default checkAuth(secretPage);
```